# Default a value for missing hash

Tags: perl

I created a hash in Perl `my %hash = (2 => 'dog', 1 => 'cat');`

When I print `$hash{3}` it errors (`use of uninitialzed value in print`) which is expected. But is there a way to default a value if not in hash?

Comment: What error do you get, and why do you expect it? I expect `$hash{1}` to evaluate to the string `cat`. Do you want to avoid an explicit default value using `$hash{9} // 'no animal'`?

Comment: The assignment you posted has a syntax error, since you are using non-ASCII quotes

Comment: I get `use of uninitialzed value in print at test.pl line 12` The values `1,2 etc`  are coming out of a database. So if the numbers aren’t in the hash I didn’t know if there was a way to assign those to some default like no animal. If `hash{3}` is in my loop from the database. I didn’t know if there was a way to display a default value of no animal.

Comment: You're not being clear on what your desired output is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
my $value = exists($hash{$k}) ? $hash{$k} : 'default';
```

To actually change the hash, use

```
$hash{$k} = 'default' if !exists($hash{k});
```

---

If `$hash{$k}` is always defined if it exists, you could also use

```
my $value = defined($hash{$k}) ? $hash{$k} : 'default';
```

which can be reduced to

```
my $value = $hash{$k} // 'default';   # 5.10+
```

To actually change the hash, use

```
$hash{$k} = 'default' if !defined($hash{k});
```

or

```
$hash{$k} //= 'default';   # 5.10+
```

---

If `$hash{$k}` is always true if it exists, you could also use

```
my $value = $hash{$k} ? $hash{$k} : 'default';
```

which can be reduced to

```
my $value = $hash{$k} || 'default';
```

To actually change the hash, use

```
$hash{$k} = 'default' if !$hash{k};
```

or

```
$hash{$k} ||= 'default';
```

Comment: Will try this when I get back. Seems like it will work.

Comment: Also worth mentioning you can set the value in place in the hash with: `$hash{$k} //= 'default';`

Comment: @Grant: That will corrupt any elements that actually exist but whose value is `undef`

Comment: Well obviously. My suggestion was made in the context of @ikegami explaining `$hash{$k} // 'default'` for cases where values are always defined if present.

Comment: @Grant McLean, Added your suggested change. Ignore the troll

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at the
[`Hash::DefaultValue`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::DefaultValue)
module which allows you to specify a value for a hash that will be returned instead of `undef` if an element doesn't exist

Comment: Will this a try in the future.  New to Perl so I only use it every so often.  Thanks for this bit of advice.

Comment: @user: It's not like forking out for a new Ferrari! You just install the module, add a couple statements, and then use the hash as normal.